# Publishing my API project in another IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, iis, publishing

I've published my API project several times and it doesn't have any problem. but when I publish the same publish files in one of my server's IIS it rise a error about one of my controllers. 
I've checked it, it works properly in my local and another IIS.

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.  An error
>   has occurred.  An error occurred when
>   trying to create a controller of type 'CityController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
>   
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
>     An error has
>   occurred.  Type
>   'Jabama.Web.API.Controllers.CityController' does not have a default
>   constructor 
>   System.ArgumentException 
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

I checked all of the `cityController`'s dependencies, there isn't any problem in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong. when I published the API project, it didn't publish the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Type dll` in it's bin folder.I copyed the dll manualy to that IIS and it's work but I don't know why it was giving me such an error! and even yet now what was wrong with my new IIS which the API didn't work without this dll, and the other IIS worked without this even without copying it!

Comment: This makes perfect sense, and I really appreciate you taking the time to provide such a detailed response!